# Best practices when training an xgboost model as part of a larger model?

Tags: boosting, gradient-descent

I would like to train a model end-to-end that uses the output from an xgboost model as an input. I've successfully implemented full-batch gradient descent into my pipeline with jax, following this guide: [JAX vs PyTorch: Automatic Differentiation for XGBoost](https://towardsdatascience.com/jax-vs-pytorch-automatic-differentiation-for-xgboost-10222e1404ec). However, I am training the rest of my model with stochastic gradient descent (ideally with Adam, if that matters).

What are the best practices for end-to-end training here? Should I be computing xgboost outputs for every training example, then storing the gradient/Hessian until the end of each epoch and passing that back to xgboost? Or is there a principled way of updating the xgboost model along with everything else on each SGD step?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.